# Haskell: How to return a list of possible splits of a list

Tags: list, haskell

I'm trying to write a function named split that takes a list and returns a list of pairs of all the different possiblities to partition it, e.g.

```
split [4,3,6] = [([],[4,3,6]),([4],[3,6]),([4,3],[6]),([4,3,6],[])]
```

Now I wrote this

```
split :: [a] -> [([a],[a])]
split []     = [([],[])]
split (x:xs) = ([],(x:xs)):(zip (map (x:) (map fst split(xs))) (map snd split(xs)))
```

piece of code and Hugs and the interpreter of my choice gets me this

```
ERROR file:.\split.hs:3 - Type error in application
*** Expression     : map snd split xs
*** Term           : map
*** Type           : (e -> f) -> [e] -> [f]
*** Does not match : a -> b -> c -> d
```

error message. What the heck am I doing wrong? Why would (map snd split xs) be of type
(a-> b -> c -> d)?

Comment: Is ([4,6],[3]) also in the result? Because it fits your description. And if it is in there, the answer of Nicolas Wu is not sufficient

Comment: No, it's not a result and I am sorry if my description suggests that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You've misplaced your parens. Try

```
split (x:xs) = ([],(x:xs)):(zip (map (x:) (map fst (split xs))) (map snd (split xs)))
```

Haskell doesn't use parenthesis for function calls in the same way as something like C and Java. When you write `map fst split(xs)` this is the same as `map fst split xs`, i.e. the compiler thinks that you are trying to call `map` with three parameters. Therefore you need to parenthise the call to `split` like this: `map fst (split xs)`.

What you are effectively trying to write is a simple [zipper](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Zipper) for a list. The easiest way to implement it is

```
import Data.List (inits, tails)

split xs = zip (inits xs) (tails xs)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, for the parens and the much simpler code. I was being very blind.

Answer (score 6):

Here's an alternative definition:

```
splits :: [a] -> [(a, a)]
splits xs = map (flip splitAt xs) [0 .. length xs]
```

Admittedly, it's not very efficient, but at least it's concise :-)

Another version that's even shorter, and probably more efficient, using `inits` and `tails` from `Data.List`:

```
splits :: [a] -> [(a, a)]
splits xs = zip (inits xs) (tails xs)
```

Now let's have a little fun. We can write `inits` and `tails` as `foldr`s, where we use `initsA` and `tailsA` to represent what are known as the *algebras* of the folds:

```
inits :: [a] -> [[a]]
inits = foldr initsA [[]]

initsA :: a -> [[a]] -> [[a]]
initsA x xss = [] : map (x:) xss

tails :: [a] -> [[a]]
tails = foldr tailsA [[]]

tailsA :: a -> [[a]] -> [[a]]
tailsA x xss = (x : head xss) : xss
```

Using these algebras, we can further combine them:

```
splits :: [a] -> [([a], [a])]
splits = foldr splitsA [([], [])]

splitsA :: a -> [([a], [a])] -> [([a], [a])]
splitsA xy xyss = zip (initsA xy xss) (tailsA xy yss)
  where (xss, yss) = unzip xyss
```

So now we have `splits` defined as a single `foldr`!

Comment: Thanks alot, especially for the additional explanations. You forgot the list-parentheses, however. :)